# How to calculate the p-value based on Ci intervals and standard error on R?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

Today when I try to run the code on R and get the results with low and high confident intervals and standard error regarding the Difference-in-Difference estimator:

> did_imputation(data = castle, yname = "l_homicide", gname = "effyear",
> first_stage = ~ 0 | sid + year,
> tname = "year", idname = "sid")

And result is

[image]

I am wondering how to calculate the p-value of this estimate manually and better if there is a code on R to deal with that.
Many thanks and warm regards.

Update: I found the link [here](https://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304?fbclid=IwAR3oICx8b26FCvl8DyS2PvTSBLbn_ybKisfzS76WAaWi1C_1mfpPJ-npmus) about calculating manually, but I am wondering how to find p-value using R based on the given data
I also found a way to code in R but I am not sure if we just have a package for that

[image]

Comment: This would be a t-test of the regression coefficient, right? How many standard errors is the estimate from the value under the null hypothesis (probably zero)?

Comment: @Dave, it would be a t-test, and yes for the second question, I found a way out but I am wondering is there any a package

Comment: Base R is great at calculating t-distribution probabilities through the pt function.